# Showing that $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n+1)^2 z^n$ is continuous in the open unit disk $|z| <1$

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, power-series

So I figured since its a power series that maybe finding the radius of convergence here would be useful. So as $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n+1)^2 z^n$ we can find the radius of convergence as$$R= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+2)^2}\right| = 1.$$Since the radius of convergence is greater than $0$ we have that the function is analytic. Since the function is analytic it is continuously differentiable, so since the function is differentiable, can we just conclude that the function itself is continuous as well in the unit open disk? Or am I going about it wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine, but why all those intermediate steps? When the radius of convergence of a power series centered at $a$ is $R$, its sum defines a continuous function on $D(a,R)$. That's all.

Comment: Gotcha, the reason I did it the way I did was because I didn't see that I could use what you did, thank you!

Comment: If its continuous in the open disk, is it necessarily continuous on the disk itself when $|z| =1$